# Can't get my new Asus Vivobook 15 to boot from USB

Tags: bios, asus-laptop

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daafw.jpg

I've went through the "whole" internet and couldn't resolve my issue. All of the options that others describe are nowhere to be found on my BIOS. No Launch CSM, no Legacy Mode, etc. I've disabled Fast Boot and Secure Boot. I made the pen drive bootable using RUFUS (MBR). I used this same pen drive to install windows on my other laptop and it worked just fine. I'm kinda at the loss here at what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your BIOS doesn't seem to support CSM, also known as "legacy boot" or "BIOS boot". Only UEFI boot will work, which is not necessarily a problem.

Select UEFI mode in Rufus and it should boot fine.

Comment: _"UEFI works only with GPT"_: That is simply incorrect, but, alas, many people appear to have this misconception. UEFI is designed to works with both MBR and GPT (and no, not Legacy Mode only when using MBR, "pure" UEFI too). In other words, you can create a UEFI-only bootable media that uses MBR. In fact, Rufus allows you to do just that if you select _MBR_ for _Partition scheme_ and _UEFI (non-CSM)_ for _Target system_. So be mindful of declaring that something can't boot in UEFI mode simply because it uses MBR...

Comment: You're right, I didn't express myself clearly. Windows installations have this limitation: Windows installed on GPT disk will boot only in UEFI mode, Windows installed on MBR disk will boot only in BIOS-compatible mode. This fact is not related to OP's problem, though. I've removed misleading part of the answer. (By the way, thanks for Rufus.)